# Button Highlight

Tags: android, button

I have a keypad which i have created for my app. My problem is, I have to implement button highlight as the user slides his finger through the keys. I have tried several ways, but none works. By default when the user clicks on a new button, android highlights it for me, but when I try to move to the next button form the current button, the touch event is not working. 
how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

use the `GestureDetector with onTouchEvent`  this solve your problem. And also use the canvas to highlight the specific location .This is done based on the values return by the MotionEvent.